# Precision '41' required to send all values in column 'Divisor' exceeds the maximum supported precision '38'

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, precision, user-defined-types

I have a simple C# code to run a stored procedure using `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection`. One of the input parameters of the procedure is a user-defined data type. One of the columns in it is decimal type.

From C# code, I am sending the value for this parameter using datatable. The column types of datatable are similar to udtt including the decimal column.

When I run the code, I get this error:

> Precision '41' required to send all values in column 'Divisor' exceeds the maximum supported precision '38'. The values must all fit in a single precision

My first reaction was to check if any decimal value in the datatable has a precision more than 38. To my surprise, the max precision value for the decimal column was 32.

I tried to break the datatable rows in smaller collections to find out the exact value causing the issue. When I used collection of 50 rows to execute the procedure, I got the same error. However, when I tried collection of 10 rows, procedure execution was successful for all 10 rows collection.

I can use `decimal.Round()` to avoid the error. But this causes issues in our data.

Does anyone know why the .NET Framework throws a precision error when max precision is 32 in my data?

Comment: Have you read through the [Precision, Scale and Length](https://learn.microsoft.com/th-TH/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql) documentation yet? It shows how you can calculate the precision and scale required for the result of addition, subtraction, multiplication and division operations.

Comment: The above documentation also says, _The result precision and scale have an absolute maximum of 38. When a result precision is greater than 38, it's reduced to 38, and the corresponding scale is reduced to try to prevent truncating the integral part of a result. In some cases such as multiplication or division, scale factor won't be reduced, to maintain decimal precision, although the overflow error can be raised._

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I have gone through the documentation. All the calculations are done in C# code in my case. After the calculations, I have checked decimal column values in my c# datatable. No value has precision greater than 38. Still the error when I pass the entire datatable as proc input from c#

Comment: At a guess, I think your problem is going to be that you have decimals which are too wide ranging, some very large and some very small. Without a [mcve] we can't really help

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, decimal values range from 0 decimal places to up to 28 decimal places. If this is the issue, what can I do to verify this? Can I share an attachment here? Sorry, 1st time asked a question here.

Comment: Precision is a question also of how many *total* decimal digits it has. Eg is the highest digit of the largest value less than 10^38 of the lowest digit of the smallest value? Or something like that